# Mysql doesn't recognize mathematical operation

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following query to calculate geo distance:

```
SELECT (
   (ACOS(SIN(39 * PI() / 180) * 
         SIN(`latitude` * PI() / 180) +
         COS(39 * PI() / 180) *
         COS(`latitude` * PI() / 180) *
         COS((32–`poi.longitude`) * PI()/180)
        ) * 180 / PI()
   ) * 60 * 1.1515
       ) AS distance
FROM     `poi`
HAVING   distance <= 10
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

When I run the query I have the error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '– `poi.longitude`) * PI()/180...

So if I replace (32–`poi.longitude`) with a number like (3) then it works, but even if i use (32–21) as a mathematical operation it throws error. I replace `poi.longitude` with  `longitude` (with quotes), longitude and so on but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the proper minus sign, -.

Answer (score 3):

The reason of the syntax error is because you have wrap the table name and column name with backtick as one causing the server to find for an unknown column.

```
`poi.longitude` -- searches for column name [poi.longitude] and not
                -- [longitude] from table [poi]
```

---

it should be

```
`poi`.`longitude`
```

or

```
poi.longitude
```

Comment: I already tried all those combinations and nothing works, I updated the mysql version, it also didnt help

Comment: @ufucuk reading at the error message, the error starts at `–\`poi.longitude\``

Comment: @ufucuk "replace poi.longitude with longitude (with quotes)" -- by *quotes*, you mean single quote, double quote or backtick?

Comment: I really tried all kind of quotes you can imagine, with quotes, without quotes. For example when I try 32–poi.longitude without quotes I got the error 'Unknown cloumn 32–poi.longitude in field list'

Comment: i can't believe it's throwing *unknown column* `32–poi.longitude`. Can you post all the queries you have tried?